# Back Press for the View In Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

My problem is something similar like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36841128/onbackpressed-in-fragment-google-maps). I am working in `Skobbler map`.
I have `MainActivity` which include `HomeFragment`. My `HomeFragement` includes the `stack of view` like: `A->B->C->D`. When I reach to the `view D`, if I `back press` then I want to go back like: `D->-C->B->A`.

In my `MainActivity`, I include the `Fragment` in `onCreate` method:

```
homeFragment = HomeFragment.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.llMainActivityContainer, homeFragment)
            .addToBackStack(TAG)
            .commit();
```

and

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (!homeFragment.onBackPressed()) {
        int count = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
        if (count > 0) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            return;
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

In my `HomeFragment`, I have `onBackPress` method.

```
public boolean onBackPressed() {}
```

But, I am unable to come back from `final view` to `first view as homescreen`. What should I include here? What can be done to solve this problem?

**Add Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/rlHomeContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true">


<com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapViewHolder
    android:id="@+id/skmVHHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/chess_board_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/map_background" />

<include layout="@layout/layout_driving_direction_info" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabDrivingDirections"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fabCurrentLoc"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_panel_day_background" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fabCurrentLoc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="150dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/blue_panel_day_background" />


<include
    layout="@layout/layout_drive_info"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is the TAG set?

Comment: Can you add more about stack of view ?

Comment: TAG is nothing, `addToBackStack(string here)`, so i add that? What can I add there?

Comment: to make sure its in the same stack it should be constant string or null

Comment: `addToBackStack(null)`

Comment: pass null instead of tag and see

Comment: Okay let me check.

Comment: @SatanPandeya, How you add view in stack ?

Comment: Is there method to add view into stack?

Comment: I add my `fragment` in `onCreate` method.

Comment: did setting null work?

Comment: No, but how can I add my fragment view to stack? That's may solve the question.

Comment: where is llMainActivityContainer?

Answer (score 1):

It feels like Google missed this part when designing the fragment classes for tablets. Fragments may have an interest in handling the back button, but they don't receive any type of callback to let them know the back button was pressed.

This is how I solved that problem.

- Define an interface.  I did this as an inner interface of the activity since it's the activity that accesses those clients that implement it.

  ```
      public interface HandlesOnBackPressed {

          /**
           * Callback for back button pressed event.
           * @return true if the back press was handled so the activity doesn't need to.
           */
          boolean onBackPressed();
      }
  ```
- Fragments that have an interest in the back button will implement this interface

  ```
  public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements MyActivity.HandlesOnBackPressed {

      ...

      @Override
      public boolean onBackPressed() {

          ...
  ```
- When you do the fragment transaction:

  1. Give the `HandlesOnBackPressed` fragment a unique tag when you do the transaction (`replace` etc.)
  2. When you push the transaction to the back stack, give that back stack entry *the same tag*.

     ```
         MyFragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance(...
         fragmentManager
               .beginTransaction()
               .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, "MyFragment")
               .addToBackStack("MyFragment")
               .commit();
     ```

  The fact that I used the class name has no bearing on the logic.  The only requirement is that the fragment tag and the back stack entry tag be the same.
- And here is the secret sauce. Override `onBackPressed` in the activity:

  ```
      @Override
      public void onBackPressed() {

          FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
          int count = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
          if (count > 0) {

              FragmentManager.BackStackEntry topBackStackEntry = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(count - 1);
              if (topBackStackEntry != null) {

                  String tag = topBackStackEntry.getName();
                  if (tag != null) {

                      // since super.onBackPressed() hasn't been called yet,
                      // the top back stack entry should match with the current fragment
                      Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
                      if (fragment instanceof HandlesOnBackPressed) {

                          if (((HandlesOnBackPressed) fragment).onBackPressed()) {

                              // the fragment handled the back press, 
                              // so don't call super.onBackPressed()
                              return; 
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }

          DrawerLayout drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
          if (drawerLayout != null && drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
              drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
          } else {
              super.onBackPressed();   // pops back stack, onBackStackChanged() is called
          }

      }
  ```

Google, why do you make me do this stuff?